# Is it possible to apply a patch using libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

Is it possible to apply a patch using libgit2sharp. I am looking for an equivalent of

```
git apply --check fix_empty_poster.patch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not yet a way to apply a patch in LibGit2Sharp.

Some work has begun for [patch application in libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2280), but it is not yet complete.  Once that gets merged, then the same mechanism can be exposed in LibGit2Sharp.